# Stop Gson from serializing object in list

Tags: java, json, gson

When serializing a list of Java objects with Gson, I want the objects to be filtered so that only objects with certain values in a status field are serialized. So far I have come up with using two Gson instances, one with a custom serializer, one without

```
...
gson = gsonBuilder.create();

gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(PropertyValue.class, new PropertyValueSerializer());
strictGson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

where PropertyValueSerializer looks like this:

```
public static class PropertyValueSerializer implements JsonSerializer<PropertyValue> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(PropertyValue propertyValue, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        PropertyStatus propertyStatus = propertyValue.getStatus();
        if (propertyStatus == null || propertyStatus.isIndex()) {
            return gson.toJsonTree(propertyValue);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

That is, use default serialization or return null if the status field indicates that the PropertyValue should not be serialized. This executes, but returning null obviously doesn't work for excluding the PropertyValue object from serialization as I get JSON like this:

```
[

    {
        "status": "HasDraft",
        "sourceInfo": {
            "author": "UUU",
            "refId": "6aad7da8-e635-461d-8d42-c9a8aecd61fc"
        },
        "valueType": "TEXT",
        "value": {
            "sv": "Rojo"
        }
    },
    null
]
```

Is there a way to exclude the second PropertyValue object so I get

```
[

    {
        "status": "HasDraft",
        "sourceInfo": {
            "author": "UUU",
            "refId": "6aad7da8-e635-461d-8d42-c9a8aecd61fc"
        },
        "valueType": "TEXT",
        "value": {
            "sv": "Rojo"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I found out how to do it. I need a custom serializer for List instead of PropertyValue. In that I filter the list before using default serialization:

```
public static class PropertyValuesSerializer implements JsonSerializer<List<PropertyValue>> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<PropertyValue> propertyValues, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        List<PropertyValue> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PropertyValue propertyValue : propertyValues) {
            PropertyStatus propertyStatus = propertyValue.getStatus();
            if (propertyStatus == null || propertyStatus.isIndex()) {
                filtered.add(propertyValue);
            }
        }
        return gson.toJsonTree(filtered);
    }
}
```

Comment: "New applications should prefer TypeAdapter, whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API." You should better use TypeAdapters for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks aegean, will look into this, as I have also found a flaw in my solution (dealing with recursive structures).